# Animation loc, rot, scale and dimensions change in NLA

Tags: animation, error, nla-editor

So I am trying to combine 3 Mixamo animations together in Blender to make one fluid motion. I import the fbxs, set their location, rotation and dimensions, give them names in the dopesheet, make action strips in the NLA editor and if I play them without any changes my animation plays through. It has its jumps that I want to blend from one action strip to another.

As soon as I make any changes to the NLA (adding the blend or relocating the strips) the location, rotation and dimensions change in my animation. I’ve done this with different characters and different actions and the same thing keeps happening. Anyone have any idea on how I can get my separate animations put together to make one seamless animation??

Comment: sharing blend file would help a lot...

Comment: here's a googldrive of what I have. once you move the action strips, it changes everything about the animation.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bWAidW4bmO0WbZ6w5hg64ojgd7fFQQVl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [edit] your question and add the additional information there.